# iOS app unable to detect it's inside a CLBeaconRegion

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

We purchased a number of beacons from kontakt.io and are trying to get basic detection working with our iOS app. Bluetooth is on, and my app has "Always" location permissions. I downloaded the [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) app and entered the proximity UUID (which they all share), and that app sees the beacons, which are physically right next to me. The delegate methods in my app are not behaving as expected though.

We are building a CLBeaconRegion and calling the following:

```
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:newRegion];
[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*) newRegion];
```

Then after a short timeout calling

```
[self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:newRegion];
```

For the monitoring case, our delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(nonnull CLRegion *)region {
```

is getting called. I confirmed the UUID in the region parameter matches what I passed to be monitored. But the state is always either CLRegionStateOutside or CLRegionStateUnknown. I would expect it to be CLRegionStateInside.

For ranging, the delegate method:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
```

is getting called (somehow? not sure if that's due to requestStateForRegion), but the array is empty.

What steps can I take to troubleshoot this? I'm sort of at a loss as to what's happening behind the scenes

Comment: Can you please show your code that creates your `newRegion` just to eliminate that as a possibility of a simple error?  You may obfuscate your UUID if you wish, but make absolute sure it is exactly the same as you are seeing with the Locate app.

Comment: Oops, was a mistake on my part. Your comment prompted me to reexamine where I was making the CLBeaconRegion. I was passing 0 to the locationManager as the major and minor value to look for, when my beacon themselves all have nonzero values for those. Now I'm seeing a value of CLRegionStateInside.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the initializer for CLBeaconRegion that takes a major and minor value and passing 0 for those, though the beacons were broadcasting nonzero values. If you're just trying to get beacons up and running and focusing just on UUID, remember that you need to properly exclude these major and minor values for the time being.